# WPF itemscontrol binding problems

Tags: wpf, vb.net, binding, tabcontrol

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ExportFormat, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="1">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="{Binding}" Margin="5" Height="50" Width="70" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.setExportFormat, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"></Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

So i have that code in my xaml and the button gets filed with a list of string. Depending on what the users chooses on previous Usercontrol that item will be filed with differents items. The problem is if the user select one option at the first run the button will be filled correctly but if the user go back and select the other option the control doenst update and shows the same as before..
My english is not the best but i think i could made me understand! Any idea?!
PS: the bindind on Button is to a readOnly property so i cant define it to Mode="TwoWay".. i took a look on the debug and the property ExportFormat gets updates with the new items but the usercontrol still displays the first option!!

Sincerely Rui Nunes

Comment: What is the Type of ExportFormat on your ViewModel?

Comment: As Baboon points out - that is your problem - ObservableCollection<T> notifies subscribers (Bindings) that something has changed - List<T> doesnt.

Comment: Please don't edit SOLVED into the title or your solution into the question body. Post the solution as an answer.

Comment: @ChrisF ok i will post the solution as soon as im able, since i dont have 100 rep i have to wait atleast 6 hours to reply on my own question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide code-behind so I'm gonna take a few shots in the dark here:

- The `ExportFormat`collection is not an ObservableCollection (or more generally, doesn't implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`).
- If it actually is an ObservableCollection, you assign it directly, instead of clearing its items and adding the new ones. example:

  `ExportFormat = MyNewObsCollection; //Bad`

`ExportFormat.Clear();`

```
foreach(var newItem in myNewObsCollection)
{
   ExportFormat.Add(newItem); //Good
}
```

Side note: ExportFormat should be readonly

Comment: ok so i got my problem solved just changing the type of ExportFormat to ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of String) it was List(of String) before.. Well kinda weird why it was not working with List and worked with ObservableCollection!

Comment: Actually it's the way it is meant to be: Lists do not provide any update mechanism built in for WPF. ObservableCollection raises CollectionChanged whenever you modify the collection, and WPF subscribes to that event.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Baboon for giving me some lights on this problem. So the Solution to my problem is:

So my ExportFormat Property was defined as:

```
Private _ExportFormat As New List(Of String)
Public Property ExportFormat As List(Of String)
Get
Return _ExportFormat
End Get
Set(value As List(Of String))
_ExportFormat = value
NotifyPropertyChanged("ExportFormat")
End Set
End Property
```

and i just had to change the List(of String) to ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of String)..

```
Private _ExportFormat As New ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of String)
Public Property ExportFormat As ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of String)
Get
        Return _ExportFormat
End Get
Set(value As ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of String))
_ExportFormat = value
NotifyPropertyChanged("ExportFormat")
End Set
End Property
```

And my problems got solved.. Thanks once again!